# Include Django login form in base.html

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms

I am new to Django and I would like to include my login form in base html.

I have the following:

"registration/login.html"

```
{% if form.has_errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match.
        Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label>Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}</p>
    <p><label>Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

And i included in base.html the following:

```
{% include "registration/login.html" %}
```

It renders everything except the textboxes for the username and password. I think I am missing something.

Comment: Does it render submit button?

Comment: Yes the login button is rendered.

Comment: ewen is right I just delete my answer

Comment: When you say it doesn't render, does it render when you visit /login in your web browser?

Comment: Yes.It was just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, the the problem, I think, is you're expecting "magic".

Django's views are templates are pretty dumb. They only have the variables available to them that are passed in one of two ways:

1. Through a context_processor (see Aidan's answer)
2. Passed in when calling render (or render_to_response)

The reason the form renders when you visit `/login`, but in no other case, is because the Django view you're using `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, passed the Django AuthenticationForm into your template for you.

Review the source here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

No other view "magically" gets that variable set.

So you have to either:

1. Set it yourself in every view across your whole app
2. Use a context processor.

Here's an easy `context_processors.py` which uses the Django stuff (based on Aidan's):

```
def include_login_form(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return {'login_form': form}
```

Then, do as Aidan points out:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    #....
    'yourapp.context_processors.include_login_form'
)
```

Now, the problem is that, when you just include the template, the login form is in a variable called "login_form", but when django's built-in view uses your template, it's in a variable called "form".

So that's an ordeal without a good "clean" solution, though I'm sure one could sort it out.

Maybe check the context passed in in your context_processor, and if a variable already exists called "form", see if it's an instance of AuthenticationForm, and if it is, use it instead.

Comment: I think that's the answer OP requires. +1 from me.

Comment: Can you please post an example on how to use this context processor in the template?

Comment: Context processors just add their variables to every single view (so long as said view uses RequestContext). So you'd just update your existing template, replacing "form", with "login_form" (though it'll break if you try to use with the contrib view as I mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like the form isn't actually being passed to the template. If you want the login form to be included on every page then you probably want to add a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors).

Create a context_processors.py file, something like -

```
def include_login_form(request):
    form = YourLoginForm()
    return {'login_form': form}
```

Then add your new context processor the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting -

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    #....
    'yourapp.context_proecssors.include_login_form',
)
```

This will mean that the context variable `login_form` is available to all your templates.

Comment: So I cannot use the django.contrib.auth.views.login any more, I have to create my own login form?

Comment: You can. Answer my question above and I'll explain.

Comment: Yes @JackShedd. It was just fine.