# Django: issue displaying login form within another view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm building a Django app where I show a landing page if there's no user logged in. I've followed [setup steps](https://realpython.com/django-user-management/) and the default login page works like a charm, accessed from: accounts/login/. **Now I'd like to display that login form from within my landing page view.** I tried adding a context processor, but it's not working yet. Here's all the info:

The file structure inside my templates directory is:

- myapp /landing.html
- registration / login.html

In landing.html, I have something like this:

```
{% block content %}

Welcome message, blah blah

{% include "registration/login.html"%}

More contents, etc

{% endblock content %}
```

**The issue:**
When I open the landing page, the "login" button is displayed but not the input fields! When I inspect the DOM, the table is there but the td elements are empty (see differences below). One other difference I see in Chrome inspector (not sure if it's important): in my landing.html it shows `Shadow Content (User Agent)` after each input element

Login form used on the (working) default login page:

```
<form method="post" action="/accounts/login/">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="wxidpSfyGmszybrJC38AC8kA8BTylBwiwVONPotCIqOYbkDF54Gwu1ME3lRLTxGw">
    <table>
      <tbody><tr>
        <td><label for="id_username">Username:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="150" required="" id="id_username"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="id_password">Password:</label></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" required="" id="id_password"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="">
  </form>
```

Login form that makes it into the DOM via landing.html:

```
<form method="post" action="/accounts/login/">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="zd8knaLCEclaAtNViVNSg7MgpJX15AgkzBEUNGZGGgHzdCZRLWlO80ekktVeDwqy">
    <table>
      <tbody><tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="">
  </form>
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086292/include-django-login-form-in-base-html) from 7 years ago I added a context processor, but it seemed to have no effect, so I wonder if things have changed a bit (I'm using django 3.2).

In my app directory I added context-processors.py, with this:

```
def include_login_form(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return {'login_form': form}
```

I updated my settings.py to include it this way:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'myapp.context_processors.include_login_form',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Anyone see what I may be missing? Big thanks in advance!

Comment: If you used [this template](https://realpython.com/django-user-management/#create-a-login-page), then it's a variable name issue. You're passing in the variable "login_form", through your context processor (which is smart, cause passing in "form", would conflict very easily with other templates), but you probably haven't changed the name in the template from `form` to `login_form`, specifically here: `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you!!